# What is the difference between taggerdate and creatordate for git tags

Tags: git, tags

In the documentation for [listing info for git tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), there is field for `taggerdate` and `creatordate`. What is the difference between these two? Which one indicates the time when the tag was created (annotated to the corresponding commit)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *tag object* has a `tagger` field.  A *commit object* has two fields, `committer` and `author`.  When a ref is a tag (`refs/tags/v1.2` for instance), it will typically refer:

- directly to a commit (so that this tag is a *lightweight tag), or
- to a tag object that in turn refers to a commit (so that this tag is an *annotated tag*).

It's possible for the tag to refer directly or indirectly to a tree or blob, but those are not the interesting cases here.

Use of `%(creatordate)` and `%(creator)` will grab values from the *committer* field if the tag is a lightweight tag and hence has no *tagger* field, but will use the *tagger* field if the tag is an annotated tag.

Use of `%(taggerdate)` grabs only the tagger date field.  Use of `%(tagger)` grabs only the tagger name-and-email field.  If the tag is lightweight and thus has no such fields, these will expand to nothing (empty strings).

> Which one indicates the time when the tag was created (annotated to the corresponding commit)?

Only an annotated tag has such data; if the tag is annotated, both `%(taggerdate)` and `%(creatordate)` will obtain it.  If the tag is not annotated, use whichever you want so as to get either the committer date, or nothing.